# many-to-many mapping with limited options on one side

Tags: hibernate, orm, mapping

I'm implementing a Java application which simulates a movie theater holding. One of the entities is a `Film`, this entity can have many `Genres` but there are obviously only a limited number of `Genres`. I'm not sure how I should implement this in Hibernate.

First I made an enum class `Genre` and gave the `Film` entity a `Set<Genre> genres = new HashSet<>();` attribute.

The problem with this is that the `Genre` is stored as a `BLOB` in the database, in a table created by Hibernate called `film_genres` and I would be unable to ask for all films of a particular `Genre`. (At least in my limited experience of Hibernate).

Then I thought I could populate the database at startup with all possible `Genres` where the `Genre` class looks like this:

```
public class Genre {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    private Genre() {}

    public Genre(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    private void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    private void setName(String name) {
        this.name= name;
    }
}
```

A very basic class. But now say I want to add a `Genre` to a `Film`, I can't do:

```
Film film = new Film("The Terminal");
film.addGenre(new Genre("Drama"));
```

Seeing as this would create a new `Genre` object for each film that is of genre drama. Would I then have to go to the database first to fetch the `Genre` object that is of value "Drama" and then add that object?

If that's what should be done, then I would still like to use an enum like this:

```
public enum GenreEnum {
    DRAMA("Drama"),
    ADVENTURE("Adventure"),
    ACTION("Action"),
    ...

    private String value;

    GenreEnum(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

The reason for this is that I have full control over the spelling of the initial values going into the database (the prepopulation) and the values of the enum, so I could now do this:

```
Film film = new Film("The Terminal");
film.addGenre(GenreEnum.DRAMA);
```

And then in the `addGenre` method I could do:

```
public void addGenre(GenreEnum ge) {
    Query query = session.createQuery("from Genre g where g.name = " + ge.getValue());
    Genre genre = (Genre)query.list().get(0);
    this.genres.add(genre);
}
```

I wouldn't put the transaction code in the model, but I've just put it there for simplification. I also realize the use of concatenation is unsafe.

Is this a decent solution or am I missing something simpler to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Either make the Genre as a whole a primary key

```
public enum Genre {
    DRAMA("Drama"),
    ADVENTURE("Adventure"),
    ACTION("Action"),
    ...

    private String value;

    GenreEnum(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

<compositeId>
  <key-property name="value" />
</compositeId>


Film film = new Film("The Terminal");
film.addGenre(session.load<GenreEnum>(Genre.DRAMA));

// or
for(Genre g : GetAllGenre)
    session.attach(g);

Film film = new Film("The Terminal");
film.addGenre(Genre.DRAMA);
```

or introduce a fixed Id in the enum

```
public enum Genre {
    DRAMA(1, "Drama"),
    ADVENTURE(2, "Adventure"),
    ACTION(3, "Action"),
    ...

    private int id;
    private String value;

    GenreEnum(int id, String value) {
        this.id = id;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

Film film = new Film("The Terminal");
film.addGenre(session.load<GenreEnum>(Genre.DRAMA.getId()));
```